# How to align the classes in one line

Tags: html, css

I want the div with class name `user` to be at the top of the page, rather than underneath the `card` div where it currently is.

I changed the `display:` to `absolute` and `inline-block` and that did not work either.

```css
.card {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.card:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
.card {
  height: 450px;
  width: 320px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px grey;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #564f4c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.info .name {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 9px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}
.answer, .reject {
  text-align: center;
  width: 47%;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  border-style: none;
}
.answer:hover, .reject:hover, .profile:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.answer {
  background-color: #3add0d;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reject {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff2b2b;
}

.phone {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.profile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dd520d;
  color: white;
/*position: relative;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.user {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Card</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://video.blastingnews.com/p/4/2017/02/10/en_gomez090217.jpg" alt="Selena Gomez">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="name">Selena Gomez</div>
      <div class="phone">
        <div class="answer">Answer</div>
        <div class="reject">Reject</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile">View Profile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="user">it should be at the top not here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you actually read the Help Center, maybe starting with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you putting the div in the wrong spot in the HTML?

Comment: Nevermind I understand now. See my answer, you need to float those two divs.

Comment: @RickCalder Is that really a wrong spot? :D
Let me check yours

Comment: Nope it wasn't that was before I ran your code and realized what you were trying to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up your code in jsFiddle now I see what you want.

Add `float: left` to .card and .user

Add a wrapper around the entire bit you have and add this class to it:

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

So with those floats added to your CSS classes your HTML should look like this

```
<div class="clearfix">

  <div class="card">
            <img src="http://video.blastingnews.com/p/4/2017/02/10/en_gomez090217.jpg" alt="Selena Gomez">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="name">Selena Gomez</div>
                <div class="phone">
                    <div class="answer">Answer</div>
                    <div class="reject">Reject</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="profile">View Profile</div>
        </div>
        <div class="user">it should be at the top not here</div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p>
  I'm a new div
  </p>
  </div>
```

Anything inside the clearfix div will float, anything outside of it will work as a normal div.

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/323x9oxm/

Comment: Could you accept the answer as correct then please? :)

Comment: I am sorry!
I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly move the `<div class="user">` above the `<div class="card">` in the HTML, and then remove the `display: inline-block;` from the `.card` CSS.

See updated code below:

```css
.card {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.card:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.card {
  height: 450px;
  width: 320px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px grey;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #564f4c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.info .name {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 9px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

.answer,
.reject {
  text-align: center;
  width: 47%;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  border-style: none;
}

.answer:hover,
.reject:hover,
.profile:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
  background-color: #3add0d;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reject {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff2b2b;
}

.phone {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dd520d;
  color: white;
  /*    position: relative;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.user {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="user">Look, I'm at the top now.</div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://video.blastingnews.com/p/4/2017/02/10/en_gomez090217.jpg" alt="Selena Gomez">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="name">Selena Gomez</div>
      <div class="phone">
        <div class="answer">Answer</div>
        <div class="reject">Reject</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile">View Profile</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I didn't mean to place the div "user" at the top left, I want to place it at the top of where it is right now.